# Spring Tool Suite create new spring starter project error

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I am using spring tool suite version 3.8.3. While trying to create a new spring starter project, I am getting an error.. UnknownHostException : start.spring.io. But I can create maven project and adding spring boot is working. Can any one help to get a solution. start.spring.io is reachable from my browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a proxy? So you have to configure that in your STS settings: Open the menu `windows/prefrences` and enter `proxy` and check your settings. If it works in your browser, try the `native` settings. (The proxy for maven is defined in the settings.xml, that's why this may work anyway)

Comment: Changed to native, restarted sts but still the same error message.

Comment: Have you checked if you are using a proxy in your browser? If so try with manual settings and apply the same settings as in the browser.

Comment: Thanks it was firewall that was blocking mvn to connect repo. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 2):

For my case in STS  this "https://start.spring.io/" was by default. but when i **connected to Internet** and trying to remove this using backspace and again typed same then its working.

Answer (score 1):

Open the 'Windows/Preference" then goto "General -> Network Connections"
Now add Host in "Proxy bypass" panel as "https://start.spring.io/".

Answer (score 1):

It's because you aren't connected to internet go switch on Wifi and it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Just turn back on the automatic update of Spring tool suit. It will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The default url loaded is  "http://start.spring.io/", when I changed this to  "https://start.spring.io/" it stared working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using spring tool suit version 4. while trying to create any project in sts was showing the error. Check if some other application is running on port number 8080, in my case oracle sql was running on port number 8080, so i changed the port number of sql to 9090. now STS is working

Answer (score 0):

For me it's work when I do the followig steps. `Windows/Preference` then goto `General -> Network Connections` Now add Host in `Proxy bypass` panel as `https://start.spring.io/`.

[image: SpringStarter Wizard]