# UnknownHostException: start.spring.io

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Does anyone know how to solve this UnknownHostException issue in Eclipse. It pops up quit often and I do no know how to fix it.
This also happens when I try to open the Eclipse market place.

[image: Error Pop Up]

I have tried changing the Network connections to Native, Direct, and Manual. It seems to work sometimes, but the next time i reboot, I end up with the same problem.

[image: Network Connections]

Comment: Do you need a proxy in the first place? You've turned all of them on but not filled in any of the relevant information to use them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Tool Suite create new spring starter project error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43405699/spring-tool-suite-create-new-spring-starter-project-error)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! My wifi extender was the problem. I connected directly to my home router and all my network issues were resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I tried to connect to the wifi too, and it solved the issue.